# Pump filtration of fruit liqueurs to get rid of cloudy sediment?

Tags: liqueur, filtering

Straining through muslin cloth removes large sediment particles very quickly. The next step would be to put it through coffee filter paper but over such a large quantity, this would take an unfeasible amount of time.

I'm looking to invest in a pump based filtration system that's simple, and effective - I need something that has exactly the same effect as coffee filter paper in terms of filtration level (I've read that that's about 20micrometres), just a lot quicker! Is anyone able to help advise me on where I should start?!

Answer (score 2):

There are several types of filtering systems out there. I suggest a hobby level [plate and frame filter](https://www.morebeer.com/products/beer-wine-plate-filter-kit.html). You can filter at 5 microns or less, but 5 is probably good enough to remove the sediment. There are cartridge filter systems too. But I would poke around a homebrewing or winemaking store on the web to see what is going to suit you the best.

[image: filter]

Comment: Thanks Steve for your answer. I'm currently working with the racking off and pectinase. With the purchase of huge 23L carboys it's not as laborious as I thought. I have a Harris filter in stock which I might use if it comes to it. I'll keep you posted!